# Update react-jsonschema-form to bs4

Tags: reactjs, twitter-bootstrap-3, bootstrap-4, react-jsonschema-forms

I'm experimenting with updating my React app from using react-jsonschema-form to react-jsonschema-form-bs4 and hoped it would only require a simple update of the bootstrap version.  The app loads and runs ok, but now the styling isn't displaying as it was.  For example the buttons no longer have the icons displayed so it's difficult to tell what they do.

So, my question is: should it be a simple matter of changing the bootstrap version and everything should work as before or do I need to know the differences between the versions of bootstrap and make further updates to my program/UIScheme, etc.

Here's my test React program:

```
import React, { Component }  from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
//import Form from "react-jsonschema-form";
import Form from "react-jsonschema-form-bs4";
// import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css';

const schema= {
    "definitions": {
      "Color": {
        "title": "Color",
        "type": "string",
        "anyOf": [
          {
            "type": "string",
            "enum": [
              "#ff0000"
            ],
            "title": "Red"
          },
          {
            "type": "string",
            "enum": [
              "#00ff00"
            ],
            "title": "Green"
          },
          {
            "type": "string",
            "enum": [
              "#0000ff"
            ],
            "title": "Blue"
          }
        ]
      }
    },
    "title": "Image editor",
    "type": "object",
    "required": [
      "currentColor",
      "colorMask",
      "blendMode"
    ],
    "properties": {
      "currentColor": {
        "$ref": "#/definitions/Color",
        "title": "Brush color"
      },
      "colorMask": {
        "type": "array",
        "uniqueItems": true,
        "items": {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/Color"
        },
        "title": "Color mask"
      },
      "colorPalette": {
        "type": "array",
        "title": "Color palette",
        "items": {
          "$ref": "#/definitions/Color"
        }
      },
      "blendMode": {
        "title": "Blend mode",
        "type": "string",
        "enum": [
          "screen",
          "multiply",
          "overlay"
        ],
        "enumNames": [
          "Screen",
          "Multiply",
          "Overlay"
        ]
      }
    }
  },
  UISchema={
    "blendMode": {
      "ui:enumDisabled": [
        "multiply"
      ]
    }
  },
  formData= {
    "currentColor": "#ff0000",
    "colorMask": [
      "#00ff00"
    ],
    "colorPalette": [
      "#ff0000",
      "#ff0000",
      "#0000ff"
    ],
    "blendMode": "screen"
  }

class App extends Component {
    render() {       
      return(
      <div style={{width: '90%', margin: '20px'}}>
      <Form 
                UISchema={UISchema}
                schema={schema}
                formData={formData}
                onSubmit={console.log({formData})}

              />

      </div>


      );
    }
  }

ReactDOM.render(<App/>, document.getElementById('root'));

serviceWorker.unregister();
```